# Listen to events on ElementList with no explicit accessor

Tags: dart, dart-html

Is it possible to listen to events that have no explicit accessor on an ElementList?

For example I can do the following on a single element:

```dart
this.querySelector(".js-popover-link").on["on-tap"].listen((event) {
  print("Event Triggered");
});
```

However, the following is not possible on the ElementList returned from querySelectorAll:

```dart
this.querySelectorAll(".js-popover-link").on["on-tap"].listen((event) {
  print("Event Triggered");
});
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
List<StreamSubscription> _subscriptions = <StreamSubscription>[];

this.querySelectorAll(".js-popover-link")
.forEach((e) {
  _subscriptions.add(e.on["on-tap"].listen((event) {
    print("Event Triggered");
  }));
});
```

...

```dart
_subscriptions.forEach((s) => s.cancel());
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to return a single StreamSubscription so that the listeners can be cancelled with one call?

Comment: There is no integrated way to do it (at leas none I'm aware of). I updated my answer with a simple workaround.

Comment: Thanks. That was the only way I could think of as well.