# How to add an onclick event listener to all input fields using Polymer.dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I want to add an onclick and an onchange event to all input fields inside a Polymer template.

Is there a way to add the events at once by code to all of them?
I want to avoid adding onclick and onchange attributes to the input fields one by one.

I think it must be possible, but I'm messing around with the code and I can't get it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite similar to [Listen to events on ElementList with no explicit accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630644). You might need a different selector but your question doesn't contain enough information to know what that might be. Maybe:

```
List<StreamSubscription> _clickSubscriptions = <StreamSubscription>[];
List<StreamSubscription> _changeSubscriptions = <StreamSubscription>[];

this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("input")
.forEach((e) {
  _clickSubscriptions.add(e.on["on-click"].listen((event) {
    print("Event Triggered");
  }));
  _changeSubscriptions.add(e.on["on-change"].listen((event) {
    print("Event Triggered");
  }));
});
```

to cancel the subscription use

```
_clickSubscriptions.forEach((s) => s.cancel());
_changeSubscriptions.forEach((s) => s.cancel());
```

See also [How can you assign mutliple listeners to a single StreamSubscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551007)

Comment: Thanks Günter, you are always very helpful